# ko.bindingHandler issue with Durandal

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

I'm having an issue getting Knockout binding handlers working with Durandal. I currently have a file named bindings.js that I'm loading into a viewmodel named todo.js via RequireJS. And for some reason, the binding handlers just don't seem to be attaching. Enter key doesn't work after adding a todo and hitting return on the keyboard. Any help appreciated. The code for the project is at https://github.com/robksawyer/durandal-todo. Feel free to fork it. It's also worth noting that most of the Knockout code came from the [TodoMVC Knockout+Require](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/labs/dependency-examples/knockoutjs_require/) project.

Below is a snippet of the bindings.js file. File located at https://github.com/robksawyer/durandal-todo/blob/master/scripts/bindings.js.

```
// a custom binding to handle the enter key (could go in a separate library)
ko.bindingHandlers.enterKey = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data) {
            var wrappedHandler, newValueAccessor;

            system.log("ENTER KEY PRESSED");

            // wrap the handler with a check for the enter key
            wrappedHandler = function (data, event) {
                if (event.keyCode === config.ENTER_KEY) {
                    valueAccessor().call(this, data, event);
                }
            };

            // create a valueAccessor with the options that we would want to pass to the event binding
            newValueAccessor = function () {
                return {
                    keyup: wrappedHandler
                };
            };

            // call the real event binding's init function
            ko.bindingHandlers.event.init(element, newValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data);
        }
    };
```

Here is a snippet from the HTML that is connecting the bindingHandler. File at https://github.com/robksawyer/durandal-todo/blob/master/views/todos.html.

```
<header id="header">
    <h1>todos</h1>
    <input id="new-todo" type="text" data-bind="value: current, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterKey: add" placeholder="What needs to be done?" autofocus>
</header>
```

And finally, here's a snippet from the viewmodel where it's loaded. File located at https://github.com/robksawyer/durandal-todo/blob/master/viewmodels/todos.js.

```
define(
    [
    'knockout',
    'jquery',
    'durandal/app', 
    'durandal/system', 
    'scripts/dataservice', 
    'scripts/model',
    'scripts/config',
    'scripts/bindings',
    'scripts/native'
    ], 
    function(ko, $, app, system, dataservice, model, config) {
    'use strict';

    var self = this;

    var todos = ko.observableArray([]),
        current = ko.observable(), // store the new todo value being entered
        showMode = ko.observable('all');

    // add a new todo, when enter key is pressed
    var add = function() {
        var current = current().trim();
        if (current) {
            todos.push(new model.Todo(current));
            current('');
        }
    };
    ...
```

Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding.js is not in AMD format, so I'd suggest loading it after you load knockout and not declare it as dependency. Is `scripts/native` in AMD format?

```
define(
    [
    //'knockout', // Durandal expects knockout and $ loaded via script tag,
    //'jquery',   // no need to define them as deps as well
    'durandal/app', 
    'durandal/system', 
    'scripts/dataservice', 
    'scripts/model',
    'scripts/config',
     //'scripts/bindings',
    'scripts/native' // remove if not in AMD format
    ], 
    function(app, system, dataservice, model, config) {
    'use strict';
```

Comment: Good catch. Rookie mistake. So, I've converted both native and bindings over to AMD modules and I'm still having issues. I'm new to this and also wonder if this even makes sense. Should they be modules? Or, should I add this code to the viewmodel somewhere? Anyway, I've checked in the latest code for reference. Things are running a bit better, but the ENTER KEY binding handler is still not firing.

Comment: Send you a pull requests with some modifications. https://github.com/robksawyer/durandal-todo/pull/1